# Autofac Constructor by Named property

Tags: c#, autofac

lets say i have 2 Interfaces: IProvider and IClient
Now i have 4 classes, 2 Providers and 2 Clients. every Client has an Construktor with the IProvider:

```
public interface IWebProvider : IProvider
{
}
public interface IDatabaseProvider : IProvider
{
}


public sealed class Client1 : ClientBase, IClient
{
        public Client1(IWebProvider provider) : base(provider) { }
}

public sealed class Client2 : ClientBase, IClient
{
        public Client2(IDatabaseProvider provider) : base(provider) { }
}
```

My DI Bootstraper is simple as that:

```
private void Build()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Provider>().As<IWebProvider>();
    builder.RegisterType<Provider2>().As<IDatabaseProvider>();
    builder.RegisterType<ConfigClient>().Named<IClient>("Web");
    builder.RegisterType<Client2>().Named<IClient>("Database");
    Container = builder.Build();
}
```

How can i tell Autofac wo use Provider1 in Client 1, Provider2 in Client2 without creating different Interfaces? I know i could Create an new Interface for the 2 Providers as a Proxy as a Workaround, but maybe i just use i wrong.

---

### Second Version with KeyFilter

```
private void Build()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    // Providers for Access
    builder.RegisterType<Provider>().Keyed<IProvider>("DatabaseProvider");
    builder.RegisterType<Provider2>().Keyed<IProvider>("WebProvider");

    // Clients implementing the logic
    builder.RegisterType<Client>().Named<IClient>("Web").WithAttributeFiltering();
    builder.RegisterType<Client2>().Named<IClient>("Database").WithAttributeFiltering();
    Container = builder.Build();
}

public sealed class Client : ClientBase, IClient
{
    public Client([KeyFilter("WebProvider")] IProvider provider) : base(provider) { }
}

public sealed class Client2 : ClientBase, IClient
{
    public Client([KeyFilter("DatabaseProvider")] IProvider provider) : base(provider) { }
}

public sealed class Provider : ProviderBase, IProvider
{
    public Provider(){ }
}

public sealed class Provider2 : ProviderBase, IProvider
{
    public Provider2(){ }
}
```

Regards
Lord_Pinhead

Comment: Ok, thats a lot of Interfaces at the end, but at least i dont have to create everything manually. I update my Question.

Comment: Sorry, copy paste error :) IClient is it of course. The "real" implementation has different names, i is just for easy understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to resolve named dependencies is [using attributes](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#resolving-with-attributes).

> The metadata feature of Autofac provides a KeyFilterAttribute that allows you to mark constructor parameters with an attribute specfying which keyed service should be used.

```
public sealed class Consumer
{
    public Consumer([KeyFilter("Web")] IClient client) { 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lord_Pinhead - Never mind about that last comment of mine (now deleted).

Comment: With the KeyFilter it works like a charm, thanks, i will update the second Version to my Question.